# Default size of an int variable, when an object is created?

Tags: c++, class, oop, gcc, g++

```cpp
class Vect {
    public:
        Vect(int n);
        ~Vect();
        Vect(const Vect& original);
    private:
        int* data;
        int size;
};

Vect::Vect(int n) {
     size = n;
     data = new int[n];
}

Vect::~Vect() {
    delete [] data;
}

Vect::Vect(const Vect& original) {
    size = original.size;
    data = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        data[i] = original.data[i];
    }
}

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Vect a(100);
    Vect b = a;
    Vect c;
    c = a;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a Vect class now, in main I created a Vect object that variable c holds, what will be the default size of c.size ??
Or It won't have any default?
If it does not have a default value then how does b have 100 (as in a.size is now equals b.size)?

Comment: Since there are no default constructor, there won't be a way for an instance of `Vect` to have some sort of defaults for any of its data members. The code won't compile due to no matching function call.

Comment: do you mean "default value of an int variable" ?

Comment: Non-class members (like `int` and `int *`) don't have default values. If they are not initialized they have inderterminate values and using these causes undefined behavior.

Comment: How can I have a default value to initialize ```Vect c;```

Comment: Even if you add a default constructor, this code still doesn't comply with rule-of-three, as `c = a;` is copy-assignment, which is not user-defined and therefore default-provided (i.e. member copy, which will ultimately lead to a potential memory leak after assignment and double-delete at destruction-time).

Comment: On an unrelated issue please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) On a more related note, please get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read and learn all the details about constructors and "default values" that you're wondering about.

Comment: This code won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What will be the default size of `c.size` ??*

There is no default value except if you provide one. You should have a default constructor if you want to cover it (otherwise using uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour).

For example:

```
Vect::Vect() : data(nullptr), size(0)
{}
```

---

> *If it does not have a default value then how does `b` have `100` ?*

Actually, when you write `Vect b = a;`, it is equivalent as `Vect b(a);`. In other words, the copy constructor is called (this is copy-initialization).

However, when you write:

```
Vect c;
c = a;
```

This is a copy-assignment. And you didn't provide one which is a problem because you need to handle the dynamic allocation of the `data` member (prevent self-assignment, deallocate if not `nullptr` and then reallocate with the new content), etc...
You should define the `operator=()` for the `Vect` class for your program to be well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: There is no default value of `Vect::size` unless you provide a default one in the class declaration, like

```
int size = 0;
```

If you do not initialize `Vect::size` you incur in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Further, this code has a lot of problems, and in fact it does not compile.

Essential problems:

- There is no constructor of `Vect` with no parameters, and there is not implicitly declared [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) because you define `Vect::Vect(int n)`. Hence the line `Vect c;` cannot compile.
- The code `c = a` does not call your copy constructor `Vect::Vect(const Vect& original)`, because the variable `c` already exists (assuming you have fixed the problem above). It does, instead, call the implicitly defined [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), which you have not explicitly defined. This however just copies the member variables, thus it does not have the "right" logic since, after such a copy, both `c.data` and `a.data` point to the same area of memory.  They are not a "copy", and so when `a` and `c` go out of scope, the allocated memory is freed twice (crashing the program).
  You need to define a correct copy-assignment operator `Vect::operator=`.

Other points:

- [Do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Do not include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)